# Using the bash sort command within variable-length filenames

Tags: perl, bash, sorting, command-line, awk

I am trying to numerically sort a series of files output by the ls command which match the pattern either `ABCDE1234A1789.RST.txt` or `ABCDE12345A1789.RST.txt` by the '`789`' field.

In the example patterns above, `ABCDE` is the same for all files, `1234` or `12345` are digits that vary but are always either 4 or 5 digits in length. `A1` is the same length for all files, but value can vary so unfortunately it can't be used as a delimiter. Everything after the first `.` is the same for all files. Something like:

```
ls -l *.RST.txt | sort -k +9.13 | awk '{print $9} ' > file-list.txt
```

will match the shorter filenames but not the longer ones because of the variable length of characters before the field I want to sort by.

Is there a way to accomplish sorting all files without first padding the shorter-length files to make them all the same length?

Comment: FYI -- the `sort` command is not part of bash, but a standard UNIX utility. As such, it's available to any program (and any shell).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -e 'print "$_\n" for sort { substr($a, -11, 3) cmp substr($b, -11, 3) } glob "*.RST.txt"'
```

If your perl is more recent (5.10 or newer), you can shorten it to

```
perl -E 'say for sort { substr($a, -11, 3) cmp substr($b, -11, 3) } glob "*.RST.txt"'
```

Comment: Thank you choroba (and thank you, perl). Using a version pre-5.10, so the top line works perfectly for this.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the parts of the filename which you've identified as unchanging, you can actually build a key which sort will use:

```
$ echo ABCDE{99999,8765,9876,345,654,23,21,2,3}A1789.RST.txt \
  | fmt -w1 \
  | sort -tE -k2,2n --debug
ABCDE2A1789.RST.txt
     _
___________________
ABCDE3A1789.RST.txt
     _
___________________
ABCDE21A1789.RST.txt
     __
etc.
```

What this does is tell sort to separate  the fields on character `E`, then use the 2nd field numerically. `--debug` arrived in coreutils 8.6, and can be very helpful in seeing exactly what sort is doing.

Answer (score 2):

The conventional way to do this in bash is to extract your sort field. Except for the sort command, the following is implemented in pure bash alone:

```
sort_names_by_first_num() {
  shopt -s extglob
  for f; do
    first_num="${f##+([^0-9])}";
    first_num=${first_num%[^0-9]*};
    [[ $first_num ]] && printf '%s\t%s\n' "$first_num" "$f"
  done | sort -n | while IFS='' read -r name; do name=${name#*$'\t'}; printf '%s\n' "$name"; done
}

sort_names_by_first_num *.RST.txt
```

That said, newline-delimiting filenames (as this question seems to call for) is a bad practice: Filenames on UNIX filesystems are allowed to contain newlines within their names, so separating them by newlines within a list means your list is unable to contain a substantial subset of the range of valid names. It's much better practice to NUL-delimit your lists. Doing that would look like so:

```
sort_names_by_first_num() {
  shopt -s extglob
  for f; do
    first_num="${f##+([^0-9])}";
    first_num=${first_num%[^0-9]*};
    [[ $first_num ]] && printf '%s\t%s\0' "$first_num" "$f"
  done | sort -n -z | while IFS='' read -r -d '' name; do name=${name#*$'\t'}; printf '%s\0' "$name"; done
}

sort_names_by_first_num *.RST.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, Charles, for a very comprehensive alternative. In this use-case, perl is available to the users and it's perhaps marginally easier to implement than the bash function, but I very much appreciate the option!